# unable to run the laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i got this error when i able to do "composer update" with cloned project in windows

```
"Call to a member function connection() on null"
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error 
code 1
```

this is composer.json

```
 {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "coderello/laravel-passport-social-grant": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.18.35",
        "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
        "socialiteproviders/apple": "^3.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

how i  can resolve this error i tried most of things composer update , composer install  unable to solve this error what is exactly i am missing while running laravel project also same error i got when i able to serve the project  "Call to a member function connection() on null".

also tried with composer dump-autoload

Comment: Did you configure and create a database?

Comment: yes database is configured @miken32

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you cloned this project from a repository, didn't it contain a `composer.lock` file? Running `composer update` after having cloned a project is a good hint that you forgot to commit the lock file of a working environment

Comment: let me check once hope it  will work @NicoHaase thanks for suggestion